# How to pass the Query Data in Body for making REST API call in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am doing a post operation where i am getting some response.

My URl looks Like:

```
http://domainname/api/v1:id
```

As a part of body i want to pass the below data:

```
{ elemetnt {  id, name } }
```

Can anybody suggest me how i can achieve this.

i am trying with the below code but i am getting 404:

```
let queryParam = `{ elemetnt {  id, name } }`;
    this.http.post(`http://domainname/api/v1:1`, {

                query: queryParam,



            }, {
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
                    }),
                })
                .catch((error: Response | any) => {

                    console.log(error);
                    return Observable.of(error);
                })
                .subscribe((res) => {

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

                });
```

I know i am doing something wrong. But, if somebody can help me on this then it would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on method which receiving this data, but this is correct format for you as given in question

```
queryParam= { element : { id: "0000" , name: "name" };
```

you may need to stringy your solution

Answer (score 0):

Canyou please try with

> 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

and pass json body like

```
{"query":"{ elemetnt {  id, name } }" }
```

I think this may help you